# Row-level formula field hat analyzes whether decimal amount >=.01?

Tags: reporting, formula

I need to do some math on the records in a currency column when the number isn't whole. In other words, if the number in the currency column is $10.00, I don't need to calculate; but if the currency is $5.56, I need to run a calculation. In Excel, the INT formula would make the determination — but does Salesforce offer a similar option for a row-level formula?

Comment: What is the exact scenario what formula you are using in excel ?

Comment: Can you please provide more information in salesforce we have formula field through which we can perform the row-level calculation. If you can provide exact scenario then it will be helpful to provide exact formula in salesforce

Comment: I have a solution, but thank you for asking. I was trying to calculate the original amount of a donation where the donor paid the transaction fee, since the processor charges their fee on the total amount that *includes* the fee so the original gift remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether a number is whole or not then you can do

`(ABS(<NUMBER FIELD>) - ABS(FLOOR(<NUMBER FIELD>))) = 0` in a formula field.

If this is true then yes it is a whole number else it is not a whole number.

Example: Value = 5.5

```
ABS(5.5) - ABS(FLOOR(5.5))

LHS = 5.5 - 5 = 0.5
```

Outcome = false

Example: Value = 10.00

```
ABS(10.00) - ABS(FLOOR(10.00))

LHS = 10.00 - 10 = 0
```

Outcome = true

ABS will take care of the negatives.

If you want to utilize this in reports then you can sum this field.

Comment: Thank you for your help!